# undefined reference with automake

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, linker, automake

I have a shared library(in c++) that has a function foo() (declared as extern c) which is called by a function in a project in C that is compiled by automake. so I hv a makefile.am which directs to an include.am where I have added the name and location of my library /../Release/lib/libabc.so to the xyz_LDADD variable, precisely i have
 xyz_LDADD=libabc.so

the  declaration of foo looks like this :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void foo(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

when i try to make, i get an undefined reference to foo() error.

If I change the name of d library abc, i get an error, so I assume the compiler is able to find the library.

I have also some static libraries that are working fine.
Can anybody help please.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried: `xyz_LDADD = -L/../Release/lib/ -labc`? (normally you don't put the full name of the library, just the part after the "lib" and before the ".so".

Comment: yes i tried, doesnt work :( still undefined reference error :( any other suggestions please ???

Answer (score 0):

To be called from c, a c++ method must declared with `extern "C"` or in `extern "C"` block. 
Not only in the header prototype, also in the source.

To know if this is the reason try to find the foo symbol in the `nm` tool.

like this:

`nm ../Release/lib/libabc.so | grep foo`

if you see `foo` word, without any addition, then the `foo` method declared with `extern "C"` and can be used from c code. if you see it with additional characters before or after the name, then it c++, and it cannot be used from c code.

Comment: Yes i see it without additional characters since i have extern C also in the definition of foo() :(

Comment: @tahl90 you may see it as undefined (U), you should give the code of the function with the body. what you gave is the header declaration, it didn't show how the function itself declared. it will also help if you'll give the output of the `nm` I gave you.